# r function getdate from bizdays throws error

Tags: r, date, bizdays

I have a code that worked for a long time but now it is throwing an error. When I use the function `getdate` from `bizdays` I get an error. I don't know if it is some new update, but I can't figure out whats wrong. Here is the error from an example within the function documentation, which happens to be the same error on my code:

```
getdate("last bizday", Sys.Date(), "Brazil/ANBIMA")
```

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors